# How to fix correct add to Set Hibernate Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, set

I read an article about correct redefinition equals/hashCode:
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/

These overrides are performed in order not to lose the records already written to the Set.

Code:

```
@Entity
public class Client {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Client() {
    }

    public Client(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Client client = (Client) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, client.id) &&
                Objects.equals(name, client.name);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Client{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        sb.append(", name='").append(name).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Then I test my class to make sure that it works correctly:

```
@Transactional
public class ClientTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void storeToSetBeforeMerge_ShouldBeContains() {
        Set<Client> map = new HashSet<>();
        Client client1 = new Client("John");
        Client client2 = new Client("Mike");
        map.add(client1);
        map.add(client2);

        Client merge1 = em.merge(client1);
        Client merge2 = em.merge(client2);

        assertTrue(map.contains(merge1));   // not true!
        assertTrue(map.contains(merge2));   // not true!
    }
}
```

My question is why conditions are not met. After all, I have indicated that the hashCode returns the same value: 31.
What am I doing wrong?

I can not understand the meaning of this decision. If this solution does not solve the problem, I cannot find the element I need from the Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call `persist()` before `merge()` as it is done in article. Author of the article explains it in first comment.

> Merge is for integrating changes on detached entities, which have been
>   persisted previously.

Lifecycle of a new entity begins with `persist()`. Then `merge()` is called on detached entity with ID, condition will be met.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `HashSet` is not only comparing results of `hashCode`. What it does is the following:

1. It compares the results of `hashCode` and if the results are different, then it returns true.
2. If results of `hashCode` are same, then it compares objects using `equals` and returns the result.

It's because of performance - calculating `hashCode` is faster and it is advised for the `hashCode` not to produce collisions very often.

Edit

In your `equals` method you're comparing using `id`, which is wrong as id is generated by database:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Client client = (Client) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, client.id) && // <- comparison by id
            Objects.equals(name, client.name);
}
```

In your test you're creating the objects without id and put them in `HashSet`, then you're generating id and checking the `Collection` again:

```
@Test
public void storeToSetBeforeMerge_ShouldBeContains() {
    Set<Client> map = new HashSet<>();
    Client client1 = new Client("John");
    Client client2 = new Client("Mike");
    map.add(client1); // <- those don't have an id
    map.add(client2);

    Client merge1 = em.merge(client1); // those do have an id
    Client merge2 = em.merge(client2);

    assertTrue(map.contains(merge1));   // whose with id are not in set
    assertTrue(map.contains(merge2));
}
```

Comment: can you please say how then you need to override it so that the test is executed?

Comment: The article says this is the best way - it's a tradeof between well functioning `equals` and `hashCode` when it comes to entity state and performance.

Comment: yes indeed, but I did not understand the meaning. If this solution does not solve the problem, I cannot find the element I need from the Set